# I am struggling to get my Image to load into my Cards snap-carousel, React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-snap-carousel

I am not getting any errors thrown at me so I believe it is acknowledging the image location. However I can't see them, it's been giving me a warm time. I am just trying to load the first five images at the moment

Here Is my JSON File that my cards are getting there information from:

'''code

```js
const TrailData = [
        [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Brockenhurst and the Tall Trees Trail Circular",
        location : "New Forest National Park",
        difficulty: "Moderate",
        length: 9.60,
        estimated: "3h 36m",
        distanceAway: 3.50,
        latitude: 50.8225,
        longitude: -1.5714,
        imgUrl: require("./app/assets/Lyndhurst Hill and Swan Green Circular.jpeg")  
    },
    
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Lyndhurst Hill and Swan Green Circular",
        "location" : "New Forest National Park",
        "difficulty": "Moderate",
        "length": 6.40,
        "estimated": "2h 37m",
        "distanceAway": 3.20,
        "latitude": 50.8779,
        "longitude": -1.5762,
        "imgUrl":require("./app/assets/Lyndhurst Hill and Swan Green Circular.jpeg")  
    },

    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Brockenhurst Village Walk",
        "location" : "New Forest National Park",
        "difficulty": "Moderate",
        "length": 5.10,
        "estimated": "2h 37m",
        "distanceAway": 3.7,
        "latitude": 50.8190,
        "longitude": -1.5737,
        "imgUrl":  require("./app/assets/Lyndhurst Hill and Swan Green Circular.jpeg")  
    },

    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Durdle Door",
        "location" : "Dorset Area of Outstanding Natrual Beauty",
        "difficulty": "Moderate",
        "length": 2.60,
        "estimated": "2h 37m",
        "distanceAway": 5,
        "latitude": 50.6210,
        "longitude": -2.2723,
        "imgUrl":  require("./app/assets/Lyndhurst Hill and Swan Green Circular.jpeg")  
    },

    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Tall Tress Trail Circular",
        "location" : "New Forest National Park",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 2.00,
        "estimated": "2h 37m",
        "distanceAway": 3.50,
        "latitude": 50.8226,
        "longitude": -1.5731,
        "imgUrl":  require("./app/assets/Lyndhurst Hill and Swan Green Circular.jpeg")  
    },

    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Hengistbury Head Coastal Walk",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 4.50,
        "estimated": "1h 30m",
        "distanceAway": 2.50,
        "latitude": 50.7200,
        "longitude": -1.7469
    },

    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Studland Beach and Nature Reserve",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 7.80,
        "estimated": "2h 12m",
        "distanceAway": 6.10,
        "latitude": 50.6482,
        "longitude": -1.9567
    },

    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Avon Heath Country Park",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 3.20,
        "estimated": "1h 15m",
        "distanceAway": 8.30,
        "latitude": 50.8141,
        "longitude": -1.9133
    },

    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Christchurch Harbour and Mudeford Quay",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 5.00,
        "estimated": "1h 45m",
        "distanceAway": 5.80,
        "latitude": 50.7335,
        "longitude": -1.7579
    },

    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Turk's Lane Nature Reserve",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 2.70,
        "estimated": "1h 10m",
        "distanceAway": 7.20,
        "latitude": 50.7697,
        "longitude": -1.8735
    }
],

[ 
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "The Lepe Loop",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Moderate",
        "length": 6.20,
        "estimated": "2h 15m",
        "distanceAway": 11.30,
        "latitude": 50.7924,
        "longitude": -1.3137
    },

    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Keyhaven Nature Reserve",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 3.50,
        "estimated": "1h 20m",
        "distanceAway": 13.50,
        "latitude": 50.7214,
        "longitude": -1.5643
    },

    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Highcliffe Castle to Mudeford Quay",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Moderate",
        "length": 8.00,
        "estimated": "2h 30m",
        "distanceAway": 8.00,
        "latitude": 50.7358,
        "longitude": -1.7325
    },

    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Bournemouth Seafront Promenade",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 2.60,
        "estimated": "1h 00m",
        "distanceAway": 0.50,
        "latitude": 50.7193,
        "longitude": -1.8755
    },

    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Mudeford to Highcliffe",
        "location" : "Bournemouth",
        "difficulty": "Easy",
        "length": 4.00,
        "estimated": "1h 15m",
        "distanceAway": 4.00,
        "latitude": 50.7439,
        "longitude": -1.7409
    }



    ]

]
export default TrailData;
```

'''

**This is where I am creating my cards and populating the information**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions,Image } from 'react-native';
import Carousel, { Pagination } from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
import colours from '../../colours';
//import TrailData from '../../TrailData.json';
import TrailData from '../../TrailData';
export const SLIDER_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width + 30
export const ITEM_WIDTH = Math.round(SLIDER_WIDTH * 0.7)
export const ITEM_HEIGHT = 200

//Remember to reference the package I installed to create this carousel
const MainCarousel = (props) => {
const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);
const carouselRef = useRef(null);

    const renderCard = ({item}) => (
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <Image
            source={item.imgUrl}
            style={styles.image}
            />
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.name}</Text>
            <View>
            <Text>{item.location}</Text>
            <Text>Difficulty: {item.difficulty}</Text>
            <Text>Est: {item.estimated}</Text>
            <Text> {props.milesOrkm ? `${item.length} mi long` : `${(item.length * 1.60934).toFixed(2)} km long`} </Text>
            <Text>{props.milesOrkm ? `${item.distanceAway} mi away` : `${(item.distanceAway * 1.60934).toFixed(2)} km away`}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );


    /*
    useEffect (() =>{
        const interval = setInterval (() => {
            setActiveSlide((prev) => (prev + 1) % props.TrailData.length);
        },5000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);
    */
    useEffect(() => {
      carouselRef.current.startAutoplay();
    }, []);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Carousel
            data={props.TrailData}
            renderItem={renderCard}
            sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
            itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH}
            itemHeight={ITEM_HEIGHT}
            sliderHeight={ITEM_HEIGHT}
            onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide (index)}
            activeSlideAlignment="start"
            firstItem={activeSlide}
            autoplay={true}
            enableMomentum={false}
            lockScrollWhileSnapping={true}
            autoplayDelay={1000}
            autoplayInterval={3000}
            ref={carouselRef}
            />
            <Pagination
            dotsLength={props.TrailData.length}
            activeDotIndex={activeSlide}
            containerStyle={{marginTop: -30}}// If I feel like changes this later I will
            dotStyle={{
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                borderRadius: 5,
                backgroundColor: colours.black
            }}
            inactiveDotOpacity={0.4}
            inactiveDotScale={0.6}
            />
        </View>

    )
}




const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
        paddingLeft: '2%',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      card: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F9F9F9',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        width: ITEM_WIDTH,
        paddingBottom: 40,
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
         // Adjust this value as needed
        overflow: 'hidden', // This will hide any overflowing content
      },

      image: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: ITEM_WIDTH,
        height: 200,
      },

      title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginBottom: 5
      },

      cardText : {
        textAlign: 'left'
      }

})

export default MainCarousel;
```

**Finally this where they are being rendered I apologise for the large blocks I just didn't want it to look like I missed any imports**

```js
import{View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SearchBar from '../../components/SearchBar';
import MainCarousel from '../../components/MainCarousel';
import SubCarousel from '../../components/SubCarousels';
import colours from '../../../colours';
import MetricSwitch from '../../components/MetricSwitch';
import TrailData from '../../../TrailData';
import { ScrollView, GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';



const Explore = () => {
  const topCarousel = TrailData[0].slice(0, 5);
  const youMightLike = TrailData[0].slice(5,11);
  const bikeTrails = TrailData[1].slice(0,5);
  const [displayInMiles, setDisplayInMiles] = useState(false);

  const toggleUnit = () => {
    setDisplayInMiles(prev => !prev)
  }
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    return (
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container} >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView>
          <Text style={styles.screenHeaders}>Hi User..</Text>
            <View style={styles.topElementsContainer}> 
            <SearchBar/>
            <View style={styles.MetricSwitch}>
            <MetricSwitch toggleUnit={toggleUnit}/>
            </View>
            </View>
           
            <View style={styles.topPageCarousel}>
            <MainCarousel 
            milesOrkm={displayInMiles} 
            TrailData={topCarousel}
            />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.screenHeaders}>You might Like..</Text>
            <View style={styles.subCarousels}>
            <SubCarousel 
            milesOrkm={displayInMiles} 
            TrailData={youMightLike}
            />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.screenHeaders}>For Cyclist..</Text>
            <View style={styles.subCarousels}>
            <SubCarousel 
            milesOrkm={displayInMiles} 
            TrailData={bikeTrails}
            />
            </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
        flex: 1,
      backgroundColor:colours.offWhite,
  },
    topElementsContainer : {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start'

  },
  topPageCarousel : {
    //flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  subCarousels : {
    //flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  screenHeaders: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
    flexDirection: 'column'


  },

  MetricSwitch: {
    paddingTop: '3%'
  }

});
export default Explore;
```

[![Just in case the way my project is setup is important][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejjoR.png

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Fixed, It's struggling to read the images because of the spaces in the name if I rename them to "image1" etc it renders the pictures